How to implementing Modal with Edit Record Resource Filament
How can I modify the EditRecord code in my EditPermohonan class so that when the "Save" button is clicked, a modal appears to confirm the changes before actually saving? I want the modal to display a summary of the edits, and only upon confirming the modal should the save action proceed.
Here is my code:
<?php 
use Filament\Actions;
use Filament\Actions\Action;
use Filament\Resources\Pages\EditRecord;

class EditPermohonan extends EditRecord
{
    protected static string $resource = PermohonanResource::class;

    protected function getHeaderActions(): array
    {
        return [
            Actions\DeleteAction::make(),
        ];
    }

    protected function getRedirectUrl(): ?string
    {
        return $this->getResource()::getUrl('index');
    }

    protected function beforeSave(): void
    {
        // modal goes here
        Action::make()
            ->action($this->getRecord())
            ->requiresConfirmation();
    }
}


Previously I had tried to apply the halting technique using $this->halt(), then I had also tried using handleRecordUpdate() ,but still can't show the modal.
I really appreciate any help you can provide.

The problem is you are trying to handle it from the beforeSave() method. You should write it in the getHeaderActions().
https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/panels/pages#adding-actions-to-pages
In the getHeaderActions() make the custom save action, then within use the - >requiresConfirmation() function, and - > modalSubHeading('Are you sure you want to save these changes?')
I hope it helps.
